Proving that $\int_{0}^{x} f(u)(x-u) du = \int_{0}^{x} \left(\int_{0}^{u} f(t)dt\right)du$ using FTC

Proving that $\int_{0}^{x} f(u)(x-u) du = \int_{0}^{x} \left(\int_{0}^{u} f(t)dt\right)du$ using FTC

I have tried making the following steps:
By using by parts on the LHS, we get $$\text{LHS}=\big[(x-u)F(u)\big]^x_0+\int^{x}_0F(u)du=xF(0)+G(x)-G(0)$$
where $F(u)=\int f(u)du$ and $G(u)=\int F(u) du$.
Now with the RHS, we have $$\int^u_0 f(t)dt=F(u)-F(0)$$
and $$\int^x_0\big(F(u)-F(0)\big)du=\big[G(u)-uF(0)\big]^x_0=G(x)-xF(0)-G(0)$$ which is not the same as the previous result.
What have I done wrong here?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Have you tried switching the order of integration on the RHS?

"What have I done wrong here?"
Your only mistake was when evaluating $$\big[(x-u)F(u)\big]^x_0:$$ it is not $\color{red}+xF(0)$ but
$$(x-x)F(x)-(x-0)F(0)=\color{red}-xF(0).$$
That said, there were already many proofs of this equality on MSE (including with @xpaul's approach or yours), like here and in the linked posts.

Let
$$ F(x)=\int_0^xf(u)du. $$
Then
$$RHS=\int_{0}^{x} \left(\int_{0}^{u} f(t)dt\right)du=uF(u)\bigg|_0^x-\int_0^xuf(u)du=xF(x)-\int_0^xuf(u)du=\int_0^xf(u)du-\int_0^xuf(u)du=\int_0^x(x-u)f(u)du=LHS.$$

How did you get the result of the first step?

@HBH Integrate by parts $\int_0^xF(u)du$.
